# split row in mysql check for values in between

Tags: mysql

I have a column with a bunch of rows with values like this.

> > ZIP -------- Value
> >
> > 010-212  --  **8**
> >
> > 214-268  -- **9**
> >
> > 270-324  --   **7**

I am submitting a value like 245 to mysql and trying to figure out a way to grab the associated number, which would be 9 in this case.

How would I go about writing a mysql statement and being able to tell if the number was in-between the two values in the zip row, for this example in-between and including 214-268 then use that to grab the associated value which is 9?

I feel as if I have to use SUBSTRING some how but am not sure how to go about writing it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to change structure of table a little? I suggest you to remove ZIP column and replace it by 2 columns: ZIPstart and ZIPend. Than you can easily use BETWEEN.

Comment: not sure why i diddnt think of that, that is way easier to do.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for your knowledge

```
select value from table
where 245 
between 
substring_index(zip,'-',1)
and
substring_index(zip,'-',-1)
```

I totally agree with James' advice.